# Build a Contact page in c# html

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, contact-form

First of all, I search and tryed many examples before I decided to make this question.
I'm building a website in Visual Studio 2013, in C#.

I have a [Contact page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAAjq.png) with a form that people should fill. After my search here and in several pages I couldn't make any code work for my website.

How can I make this to send the info in the form to my email?

Controller:

```
namespace SiteTESTE.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Contacto()       
        {        
            return View();
        }
```

HTML Code:

```
<body>
    <p>Se pretender mais informações sobre os nossos sistemas de relva artificial, produtos, orçamentos ou fichas técnicas, por favor não hesite em contactar-nos!</p>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
                <div id="map" style="width:100%;height:500px"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <form action="/action_page.php">
                    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="O seu nome.." required>
                    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="O seu último nome.." required>
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                    <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Escreva o seu texto.." style="height:170px" required></textarea>
                    <br />
                    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        // Initialize google maps
        function myMap() {
            var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850);
            var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
            var mapOptions = { center: myCenter, zoom: 12 };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: myCenter });
            marker.setMap(map);
        }
    </script>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBu-916DdpKAjTmJNIgngS6HL_kDIKU0aU&callback=myMap"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `form` tag have a PHP page as target in `action` attribute. Do you will use a PHP or C# to send the e-mail?

Comment: I forgot to delete that because I got some of the code from the w3schools. Sincerely, I don't know what to use. I don't know very well PHP so I would like to use C#.

Comment: Ok. (W3School is very bad in my opinion). Briefly: First you need to send the form content to an action in your Controller. After, you need a C# code to send e-mail, you can see an example here: http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-smtp-mail.htm

Comment: It is a short code. How do I send my form content to my controller? I've been searching but I couldn't get to a conclusion. Which is the port that I should choose if my e-mail endes in "@hotmail.com"?

Comment: [W3Schools isn't as bad as it used to be, but it's still iffy as a source.](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4975/why-shouldnt-i-use-w3schools-as-reference)

Comment: @jonysniper I think you would be best helped by doing some basic MVC tutorials.  This is the exact sort of thing they cover.  You'll learn more in less time that way.

Comment: You need to verify in your mail account to know the port.

Answer (score 0):

Set your form to send the content to an Action on a Controller.

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Send", "Contact")" method="post">
```

Write a code to send the e-mail.

```
public class ContactController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Send(ContatcViewModel model) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            // example code from link
            try {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

                mail.From = new MailAddress("your_email_address@gmail.com");
                mail.To.Add("to_address");
                mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
                mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from GMAIL";

                SmtpServer.Port = 587;
                SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

                SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // code
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

Is not a good practice write code to send mail in a Action. But this is an example.

The ContatcViewModel need match the forms fields.

```
public class ContatcViewModel {
    public string firstname {get; set;}
    public string lastname {get; set;}
    public string email {get; set;}
    public string subject {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: What is the best way then?

Comment: You can have an architecture where you have an Infrastructure layer responsible by, between other things, send mail.

Comment: Didn't understand

Comment: You need learn more about MVC and software architecture concepts to practice the good practices.

Comment: * Rectifying: You can USE an SOFTWARE architecture where you have an Infrastructure layer responsible by, between other things (DATA PERSISTENCE, ETC), send mail.

Comment: I just need a simple thing.. not that complex thing you are thinking

Comment: I do not think you need a complex thing. I only talked about good practice (because you asked - "What is the best way then?").